# g++ doesn't recognize the file format of a dll

Tags: dll, g++, mingw-w64

I am on Windows, and I am using the version of `g++` that comes with `mingw-64`. I have a file on my computer called `lua51.dll`. When I try to run the following command :

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o stuff.dll -llua51 stuff.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
C:/Program Files/LOVE/lua51.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

How can I fix this? Please let me know if more information is needed; I am a complete beginner to compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue you get when you try to include a 64-bit library when running a 32-bit version of `g++` or even `gcc`.

I thought that that the version of `g++.exe` that comes with `mingw-64` would produce 64-bit code, but it turns out this isn't true; it still only produces 32-bit code. In my case, `lua51.dll` is 64-bit, which is an issue since I was using the version of `g++` that produces 32-bit code.

Instead, **you need to use `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`**, which can be found in the same folder as `g++.exe`. This is the version of `g++` that will produce 64-bit code.